# Responsive image (width and height)

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I am creating a simple portfolio webpage for an photographer. He wants to show his pictures in the web. So the images should be responsive. So I wrote following code to the image class:

```
img {
    max-width: 75%;
    height: auto;
}
```

So it fits the image to the width of any screen, but I want to show the image in full height. So if the image has a bigger height, the user have to scroll down to see the whole image. So how should I set the height, so the whole image whould be shown immediately?

With regards,

Andrej

Answer (score 1):

did you try reversing the same, as in, try giving it a height, and leave the width to auto..!!!

Because u just need to set either of the two, and the other adjusts accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
max-height: 100%; /* or a bit less */
```

But note what [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) say:

> The `<percentage>` is calculated with respect to the height of the containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly, the percentage value is treated as none.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found a solution.
I just set the max-height with the vh units (viewport height).
Thx for your help.

Comment: Good one! And it looks like [`vh` has pretty good browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh).

Answer (score 0):

try this way: `img{max-width:100%; max-height:100%;}`